# IndexOutOfRange exception even when it is in range WPF

Tags: arrays, wpf

I have a very interesting question.

```
String[] values = new String[3];
values = line.Split(';');
Console.Write("Val:" + values[0] + ", " + values[1] + ", " + values[2]);
```

Could someone tell me why I get an **IndexOutOfRangeException** when it is in range?

EDIT:
The line has 3 sectors, for example `1;2;3`. 
The console writes out the `Val: ...` but in the output i still get an **IndexOutOfRangeException**.

Comment: Did you bother to test before posting? "1;2;3" works just fine with that code for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After debugging I found out that i was probably adding \n\n to the file so the next time it read from it it had an empty string under line variable. Didn't see that coming :) Thanks for @Icepickle and @Dexter for helping out :)

Edit: The problem was in the WriteLine method. I passed at the end of the string an "\n" so probably when i was reading an line I got an empty string (because two \n where at the end of the line, WriteLine in default adds an \n to the end of the string. So in result I had an "test;test1;test2\n\n".

Comment: You may want to consider [StringSplitOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx), can remove empty entries. Also feel free to post what you did as answer yourself and accept it!

Answer (score 5):

because the `line.Split(';')` overwrites the previously made assignment of `new String[3]`. In essence your string array will be as long as the nr of `';'` characters it finds + 1

If your line is something in this line: `"this; is a test"` your `values` will be a string array of length 2, and `values[2]` would be out of range

Comment: Yes, I agree but there are always 3 values in the file like "a;b;c" "1;2;3". So I should be able to read from second index. When i read from values[0] it's ok, when i read values[1] I see the value in my console but I get an indexoutofrange error after that.

Comment: Well you could debug it by setting a breakpoint on the `Console.Write` line, and investigate what is in the line, and what is the value of your `values` object. Or you could output the line before you write your values, then if an error occures you know why. Is it not possible that the last line might be an empty line, or that you have an error in your input file? @DawidDaveKosiński

Comment: After investigating the file I think that the problem the "\n". For example: my file has 2 lines: first "A;b;c" second "1;2;3", the value of line is "A;b;c" but under my values[2] i see "c1;2;3". Very odd :O I need to say that the file is correct: it has 2 lines :)

Comment: After debugging I found out that i was probably adding \n\n to the file so the next time it read from it it had an empty string under line variable. Didn't see that coming :) But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

you are splitting on ';' but you say the values are seperated by ':' (assuming you didnt typo) try this

```
String[] values = line.Split(':');
```

Comment: Sorry i did a type here, they're splitted by ";"

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you are looking for

```
Console.Write("Val:" + String.Join(", ", line.Split(';'));
```

[String.Join Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Or even 
    Console.Write("Val:" + line.Replace(";", ", ");

But I suspect you need the array for some other reason